# Sticky key activation (shift 5 times) doesn't work by hotkey ::Send {LShift 5}

Tags: accessibility, autohotkey, hotkeys

I would like to activate sticky keys by pressing 1 button, instead of pressing shift 5 times, which is the default way.

If I were to do

`F9::Send {LShift 5}`

pressing F9 will yield nothing.

I also tried

```
F9::
Send {LShift}
sleep 50
Send {LShift}
sleep 50
Send {LShift}
sleep 50
Send {LShift}
sleep 50
Send {LShift}
sleep 50
return
```

Are there any reasons as to why it's not working?

Comment: My guess is these remaps go to the application, not the OS. You need to send them to the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS:=0x003A
SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS:=0x003B
SKF_STICKYKEYSON:=0x1

VarSetCapacity(STICKYKEYS,8) ; DWORD cbSize;DWORD dwFlags;
NumPut(8,&STICKYKEYS,"UInt")
F9::
  DllCall("SystemParametersInfo","UInt",SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS,"UInt",8,"PTR",&STICKYKEYS,"UInt",0)
  dwFlags:=NumGet(&STICKYKEYS,4,"Uint")
  If (dwFlags & SKF_STICKYKEYSON)
    dwFlags-=SKF_STICKYKEYSON
  else dwFlags|=SKF_STICKYKEYSON
  ToolTip % "STICKYKEYS are " (dwFlags & SKF_STICKYKEYSON ? "ON" : "OFF")
  SetTimer,ToolTipOff,-1000
  NumPut(dwFlags,&STICKYKEYS,4,"UInt")
  DllCall("SystemParametersInfo","UInt",SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS,"UInt",8,"PTR",&STICKYKEYS,"UInt",0)
Return
ToolTipOff:
```

The code is from the Autohotkey forums at http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=93650

A note for anyone wanting to use the code: I think you have to put it at the top of your script for it to work. In my script of hotkeys, placing it in the middle, and pressing F9 to activate sticky keys caused some weird things to happen: The cursor jumped around, some folders were launched, the script exited, etc. I'm guessing that it activated other hotkeys nearby?

Answer (score 0):

While there is most likely a way to do a dll call or something complicated, it is also possibly to program similar functionality using AutoHotkey.  This would also avoid the sticky keys prompt, and you can do a traytip instead.

```
stickykeys = 0

F9::
    stickykeys:=!stickykeys
    Traytip, Sticky Keys, % (stickykeys) ? "On" : "Off"
    return

#If stickykeys

    *$Shift::
        key = 0
        Input, key, L1 M
        SendInput {Shift Down}{%key%}{Shift Up}
    return

    *$Ctrl::
        key = 0
        Input, key, L1 M
        SendInput {Ctrl Down}{%key%}{Ctrl Up}
    Return

    *$Alt::
        key = 0
        Input, key, L1 M
        SendInput {Alt Down}{%key%}{Alt Up}
    Return
#If
```

F9 simply toggles sticky keys on and off.

Note: This is using AHK_L which supports [#If](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script. I noticed that shift worked for letters, but shift, and then an arrow key for contiguous character selection didn't seem to work. Ctrl didn't work either. 



I was directed to DLL on the Autohotkey forums also. It's probably best to just use the native sticky keys and not simulate. I'm currently studying up on DLL, and I'll update this post with an answer when I find it.